# Excel VBA is not using the state I saved previously in a hidden sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to save six variables that account for the beginning and end of a table in Excel, which is divided into three sections: Fix Costs, TM Costs, and Recurrent Costs.

I've written VBA code to add or remove rows in each of these sections, and I update the relevant variables each time I make a change to the table.

The rest of the code is working as expected.

My issue is that When I reopen the Excel file, even though the correct values are in the variable sheets, they are once again canceled out. As a result, the code reverts them to their initial values, which are set to the first row of each section. This causes me to lose the count of rows I've added in previous sessions."

In This Workbook I have the code below (no declaration of variables)

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ' Load variables from the "variables" sheet
        FixStartRow = Sheets("variables").Range("B1").Value
        LastRowFixCharges = Sheets("variables").Range("B2").Value
        TMStartRow = Sheets("variables").Range("B3").Value
        LastRowTMCharges = Sheets("variables").Range("B4").Value
        RecurringStartRow = Sheets("variables").Range("B6").Value
        LastRowRecCharges = Sheets("variables").Range("B6").Value
End Sub
```

In Module 1 (Cost Spreadsheet) I have this code and in each of my routines I call 'SaveVariablesToSheet' as last statement. I am not copying all the code just the code that is associated with the button to insert a row in the Fixed Costs area:

```vb
Public FixStartRow As Integer
Public LastRowFixCharges As Integer
Public TMStartRow As Integer
Public LastRowTMCharges As Integer
Public RecurringStartRow As Integer
Public LastRowRecCharges As Integer

Sub SaveVariablesToSheet()
  
    ' Store the variables in cells
   
        Sheets("variables").Range("B1").Value = FixStartRow
        Sheets("variables").Range("B2").Value = LastRowFixCharges
        Sheets("variables").Range("B3").Value = TMStartRow
        Sheets("variables").Range("B4").Value = LastRowTMCharges
        Sheets("variables").Range("B5").Value = RecurringStartRow
        Sheets("variables").Range("B6").Value = LastRowRecCharges

End Sub

Sub InsertRowFixedCharges_Click()
  
    If FixStartRow = 0 Then FixStartRow = 13
    If LastRowFixCharges = 0 Then LastRowFixCharges = 13
    If TMStartRow = 0 Then TMStartRow = 17
    If LastRowTMCharges = 0 Then LastRowTMCharges = 17
    If RecurringStartRow = 0 Then RecurringStartRow = 22
    If LastRowRecCharges = 0 Then LastRowRecCharges = 22
 
     With Sheets("Cost Spreadsheet")
        ' Insert a new row at the position
        .Rows(LastRowFixCharges + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown

        ' Clear values in the newly added row from columns B to O
        .Range("B" & LastRowFixCharges + 1 & ":O" & LastRowFixCharges + 1).ClearContents
    End With
    ' Increment the variables for the next time the macro is run
    LastRowFixCharges = LastRowFixCharges + 1
    TMStartRow = TMStartRow + 1
    LastRowTMCharges = LastRowTMCharges + 1
    RecurringStartRow = RecurringStartRow + 1
    LastRowRecCharges = LastRowRecCharges + 1
       
    SaveVariablesToSheet
        
End Sub
```

To create the code for saving the variables in an hidden sheet in Excel I used what is written here:
[Saving State and Preventing State Restart in Excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867588/saving-state-and-preventing-state-restart-in-excel-with-vba)

I was expecting my code to use the latest value of the variables when the spreadsheet is open so the new added columns will be in the correct position.

Comment: You could add `ThisWorkbook.Save` to `SaveVariablesToSheet()` to protect against closing without saving.